# python cgi.FieldStorage is empty on chunked transport of type multipart/form-data

Tags: python, apache, cgi

Tested by apache-2.2.22 the python 3.3 cgi.FieldStorage() works perfectly for multipart/form-data if Content-Length is specified, however, the form data is empty if chunked transport is used. Please see the following two test cases.

Test_input_ok:

```
POST /cgi-bin/1.cgi?bla=ddd HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=abcdefghdddddd
Content-Length: 162

--abcdefghdddddd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="freemind"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

aaaaaaaaaa

--abcdefghdddddd--
```

FieldStorage result is OK: `FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('bla', 'ddd'), FieldStorage('filename', 'freemind', b'aaaaaaaaaa\r\n')])`

Test_input_chunk_transport:

```
POST /cgi-bin/1.cgi?bla=ddd HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=abcdefghdddddd

A6

--abcdefghdddddd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="freemind"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

aaaaaaaaaa

--abcdefghdddddd--

0
```

- Fieldstorage result for the mime attachment is empty (however, at least, present): `FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('bla', 'ddd'), FieldStorage(None, None, '')])`

The apache server does not log any errors.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The answers here might help you: http://pythonpaste.org/archives/message/20090313.212230.263b0ffc.da.html

Comment: What was in there?